# Heat equation damps backward heat equation?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory

In a previous question [on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/385992/backward-heat-equation-and-forward-perturbed-heat-equation-well-posed), I was wondering about the following:

Let $\Delta$ be the Laplacian on some compact interval $I$ of the real line with let's say Dirichlet boundary conditions. And $f_{\alpha}(x)=\alpha \cos(x)$.

The functional calculus allows me to study $S_t = e^{-\Delta t}$ and $T_t(\alpha) = e^{(\Delta+f_{\alpha})t}.$

Here $T_t$ is a perturbed heat semigroup and $S_t$ the backward heat semigroup.

Michael Renardy essentially showed that for $S_1T_1$ to be a bounded operator on $L^2$, $f$ would have to be even better than analytic and it was not even clear, if $f$ would not even have to be constant in order for $S_1T_1$ to be bounded on $L^2(I).$

This analysis was refined by Willie Wong who showed that the composition $S_1T_1$ can still be unbounded in a rather dramatic way, as he observed [here.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/386449/mapping-properties-of-backward-and-forward-heat-equation?noredirect=1&lq=1)

**The question** : I think the issue with studying $T_1S_1$ lies in the unboundedness of the operator $S_1$. Therefore, I want to study now the self-adjoint operator $Z(\alpha):=T_1(\alpha)S_2T_1(\alpha)$. This one is still possibly unbounded, but I can now use the functional calculus to regularize it. Namely, since $Z(\alpha)$ is positive-definite, we can study the now bounded operator

$$ Q(\alpha):=\frac{Z(\alpha)-1}{Z(\alpha)+1}.$$

**I would like to ask now:** Is it true that as a bounded operator $$\lim_{\alpha \downarrow 0}Q(\alpha)=0?$$

or perhaps as a **starter question**, do we have it at least strongly?

Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Do you mean $T_1S_2T_1\le c{\bf id}$ ?

Comment: I should say that I changed the question slightly, so that Denis Serre's question no longer directly applies, in case it is confusing to some people